# composer update failed with error: Invalid username or password

Tags: symfony, composer-php

php composer.phar diagnose result:
Checking platform settings: FAIL
The xdebug extension is loaded, this can slow down Composer a little.
 Disabling it when using Composer is recommended.
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity: OK
Checking github.com oauth access: FAIL
The oauth token for github.com seems invalid, run "composer config --global --unset github-oauth.github.com" to remove it
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version: FAIL
You are not running the latest version
Can anybody help me ?Thank you?

Answer (score 2):

You should run `composer config --global --unset github-oauth.github.com` and retry.
Or `composer update --prefer-dist`